# passing data from a react based component to vanilla js class

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I am trying to pass data from react class base component to a vanillajs class so this class is able to render D3 bar chart , 
I've tried passing the data from the react component through the contractor of the vanilla class , i have the data available in the vanilla class when i try to consol log it , but when i want to call the data variable in the method call d3.data() it is empty , here is the code

React class

//imports..

```
      const _data = []
      const firebaseConfig = {
          //configuration .. 
      };
      // Initialize Firebase
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      const db = firebase.firestore()
      class TableOfD3 extends Component {
        constructor(){
          super()
          this.svgId = `SVG_${uuid()}`


        }
       getData(){ 
       db.collection('db').get().then( res=>{
            res.docs.forEach(doc => {
             _data.push(doc.data())
            })
        }
        componentDidMount(){

          this.start()
        }

        componentDidUpdate(){

          this.start()

        }
        start(){
          this._graph = new D3TableEngine('#' + this.svgId,_data)
          this._graph.start()
          }

        render() {

          return (
            <div>
              <svg  id={this.svgId}></svg>
            </div>
          );
        }
      }

      export default TableOfD3;
```

// vanillajs class

```
export default class D3TableEngine {
        constructor(svgId, passedData) {

          this._svg = d3.select(`${svgId}`);
          this._svg.attr('width', _WIDTH)
          this._svg.attr('height', _HEIGHT)
          this._passedData = passedData
          }


        start() {
          const self = this;
          var _g = self._svg;

          const graphWidth = _WIDTH - _MARGIN.left - _MARGIN.right
          const graphHeight = _HEIGHT - _MARGIN.top - _MARGIN.bottom

          const graph = _g.append('g')
          .attr('width', graphWidth)
          .attr('height', graphHeight)
          .attr('transform', `translate(${_MARGIN.left + 20}, ${_MARGIN.top})`)

          const xAxisGroup = graph.append('g')
            .attr('transform', `translate(0,${graphHeight })`)
          const yAxisGroup = graph.append('g')

          const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
              .domain([0,d3.max(self._passedData, (d) => d.orders)])
              .range([graphHeight,0])

          const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
              .domain(self._passedData.map((el) => el.name))
              .range([0,500])
              .paddingInner(0.2)
              .paddingOuter(0.2)

          const rects = graph.selectAll("rect").data(self._passedData);

              rects
            .attr("x", (d)=> xScale(d.name))
            .attr("y", (d) => yScale( d.orders))
            .attr("height", (d)=> graphHeight - yScale( d.orders))
            .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth)
            .attr('fill', 'blue')

          rects
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", (d)=> xScale(d.name))
            .attr("y", (d) => yScale( d.orders))
            .attr("height", (d)=> graphHeight - yScale( d.orders ))
            .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth)
            .attr('fill', 'blue')

            const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
            xAxisGroup.call(xAxis)
            const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
              .ticks(5)
              .tickFormat((d) => 'Orders  ' +d  )
            yAxisGroup.call(yAxis)

            xAxisGroup.selectAll('text')
            .attr('transform', 'rotate(-40)' )
              .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
            } )
        }

        refresh() {}
      }
```

Comment: Is `getData` method ever called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-wrote your React class because you were doing many things that would be considered anti-pattern. In general, you want to shove as much as you can in `this.state`. Otherwise, you miss out on the main advantage of React - and that is optimally re-rendering the DOM when variables change. I think the main issue you're likely having is that you're updating the DOM from componentDidUpdate(), which will fire another update. It'll continue infinitely and crash. I would *strongly recommend* refactoring `D3TableEngine` into a React Component instead of a plain JS class. The challenge is that the way you have written the d3 component, it has to be destroyed and re-created for each render, which is a problem because React doesn't know what to do other than re-create it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class TableOfD3 extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    const firebaseConfig = {
      //configuration .. 
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const db = firebase.firestore();

    this.state = {
      svgId: `SVG_${uuid()}`,
      data: [],
      db: db
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const response = await this.state.db.collection('db').get();
    const data = response.docs.map(doc => doc.data());

    this.setState({
      data
    });
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <D3TableEngine
          id={this.state.svgId}
          data={this.state.data}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

UPDATE: I gave a shot at refactoring your d3 class into a React Component. The important pieces here are the `ref`, which let's you get a reference to the element so `redraw` can execute all the d3 code on the right `svg` element. Then, inside `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`, you must call `redraw`. However, I would refactor the `redraw` method to break out the parts that will change from the parts that will not change (eg: move the graph pieces into a different function and call that in `componentDidUpdate`). We do this so that React is performing as expected and only updating the elements in the DOM that have changed. If you need additional help, you may take a look at this [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/mrovinsky/L1qx1kyb/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=L1qx1kyb)/[medium article](https://medium.com/welldone-software/d3-and-react-working-together-353d12c2a3bc).

```
const MARGIN = 0;
const WIDTH = 0;
const HEIGHT = 0;

class D3TableEngine extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    redraw();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    redraw();
  }

  redraw = () => {
    this.svg = d3.select(this.svg);
    const graphWidth = WIDTH - MARGIN.left - MARGIN.right
    const graphHeight = HEIGHT - MARGIN.top - MARGIN.bottom

    const graph = this.svg.append('g')
      .attr('width', graphWidth)
      .attr('height', graphHeight)
      .attr('transform', `translate(${_MARGIN.left + 20}, ${_MARGIN.top})`)

    const xAxisGroup = graph.append('g')
      .attr('transform', `translate(0,${graphHeight})`)

    const yAxisGroup = graph.append('g')

    const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(props.data, (d) => d.orders)])
      .range([graphHeight, 0])

    const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
      .domain(props.data.map((el) => el.name))
      .range([0, 500])
      .paddingInner(0.2)
      .paddingOuter(0.2)

    const rects = graph.selectAll("rect").data(props.data);

    rects
      .attr("x", (d) => xScale(d.name))
      .attr("y", (d) => yScale(d.orders))
      .attr("height", (d) => graphHeight - yScale(d.orders))
      .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth)
      .attr('fill', 'blue')

    rects
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", (d) => xScale(d.name))
      .attr("y", (d) => yScale(d.orders))
      .attr("height", (d) => graphHeight - yScale(d.orders))
      .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth)
      .attr('fill', 'blue')

    const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)

    xAxisGroup.call(xAxis)

    const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
      .ticks(5)
      .tickFormat((d) => 'Orders  ' + d)

    yAxisGroup.call(yAxis)

    xAxisGroup.selectAll('text')
      .attr('transform', 'rotate(-40)')
      .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <svg
        id={this.props.svgId}
        width={WIDTH}
        height={HEIGHT}
        ref={el => (this.svg = d3.select(el))}
      >
      </svg>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation 
I've just tried your code and i'm getting  " Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops."
  

in     this.setState({ 
     d3Table  });

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I said would happen. Sorry I didn't update the react class. I will do that.

Comment: I updated the react class so it *should* work - may need some additional tweaking though, but at least it puts you on the right path.

Comment: You may want to check out [react for beginners](https://reactforbeginners.com/) if you new to React. I don't make any money off of the recommendation of the course.